# When does Soul Society arc start and finish?

Tags: bleach

In *Bleach*, which episode does the Soul Society arc start, and what episode does it finish?

Also what manga chapter does it start at and what manga chapter does it finish at?

Answer (score 1):

In the anime, the Soul Society arc is covered in episode 21 through 63.

- Soul Society: The Sneak Entry arc (Episodes 21-41)
- Soul Society: The Rescue arc (Episodes 42-63)

source: [Bleach fandom](https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/Episodes)

In the manga it is covered in volume 9 through 20 which corresponds with chapters 71 - 178.

source: [Bleachmedia fandom](https://bleachmedia.fandom.com/wiki/Soul_Society_Arc)